# server-push: update multiple clients with varying data

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, server-push

Is it possible to update multiple clients with varying data using ICEpush or something similar? And how?

That is, consider having a real-time application (I'm using JSF) that brings two user groups (clients) together, the "providers" and "buyers". When a provider makes his offer the server will pick only one buyer according to some matching algorithm and push to him the offer. The other buyers/clients will get a different notification pushed from the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer) You want to do a broadcast to all, and then a single push for the buyer.